# Powershell - Calling VBoxManage.exe in a Script

Tags: powershell

```
[string]$VBoxManage="`"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe`""
[string]$VMtoClone="`"C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\CloneMe\CloneMe.vdi`""
[string]$VMCloned="`"C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\CloneMe\CloneMe_2.vdi`""
[string]$cloneVDI="clonevdi"

Write-Output ($VBoxManage + " " + $cloneVDI + " " + $VMtoClone + " " + $VMCloned)

$commandtoinvoke=($VBoxManage + " " + $cloneVDI + " " + $VMtoClone + " " + $VMCloned)

Invoke-Expression  $commandtoinvoke
```

I'm using a powershell script to clone a virtual machine. The issue I'm having this the following error:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:53
+ "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevdi "C:\Users\someuser\Virt ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'clonevdi' in expression or statement.
At line:10 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression  $commandtoinvoke
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

What does this error mean? How did I prevent it from happening?

Comment: What happens if you do `Invoke-Expression "$VBoxManage $cloneVDI $VMtoClone $VMCloned"`?

Comment: @arco444 - Still the same error, it fails at the clonevdi part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Invoke-Expression in this case, it will try to parse the string in expression parsing mode, that's why it's called Invoke-Expression. Better use the call operator in this case:

```
& $VBoxManage $cloneVDI $VMtoClone $VMCloned
```

Note that there is no need to quote the arguments, that's done automatically.

See https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/
and about_Parsing.